# Local update using OStree

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, updates, yocto, ota

I am considering OStree for updating my embedded devices. I understand that its used primarily as an OTA solution, but I would like to update devices locally as well, by just moving files from my computer to embedded device for quick fix or debugging.
After reading docs and few articles about it, it seems  impossible because the system must be read only and any change would break the deployment, if I put the files into /etc or /usr than ostree can't track them.  I know I can update it locally by having  OStree repository on my machine, but that would mean I have to keep track of remote repository on my machine as well so I don't overwrite the latest changes. Do I understand OStree correctly? Is there any other way than having OStree repository on my machine ?

I know I can get info by just playing with OStree but I dont wanna waste 3 days to just find its impossible and I have to use something else.

Comment: If the system is read-only, you can have symbolic links to another partition which is in read/write (`/data` for example), and directly send files to this partitions. It works, but I don't recommend it for production.

Another solution would be to use opkg packages (no OStree), and setup an opkg server on you computer, pointing to the packages generated by Yocto. It is much simpler to setup for quick tests.

Comment: The symbolic link to another partition sounds like it could work, I could change the symlink and after local  update and then after updater from ostree server it would change back so the system would be again in consistency with server. opkg doesn't really work because its not atomic which is one of my requirements.

Comment: Another way would be to do an overlayfs where you have some amount of storage set aside for overlaid operation- this has the effect of letting you do what you wanted to do and yet have a largely immutable underlying layer.